# Admin cookie deleted on image upload

Tags: admin, session

When I upload an image for a product Magento is deleting my admin cookie, so when I go to 'save' I am returned to the admin login page. I am really not sure what's going on. Any ideas?

```
My cookie path is /
My cookie domain is empty
Use http only is no
Restriction mode is no

ALL session validation settings are no including 'Use SID'

I get no errors or exceptions and nothing in the console.
```

Also, my WHOLE site is severed over HTTPS and I don't seem to have any other session or cookie issues.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you use the flash uploader (for ex. in the media gallery) or upload an image in the System Configuration (for ex. store logo)?

Comment: It's the flash uploader on product images.